# MVC logging with Serilog not serializing objects

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights, serilog

MVC Core web service project, using AspNetCore 2.0.0 and Serilogger 2.0.2.

In one of our controllers, I'm playing around with logging request data to Application Insights using Serilog.

In our Startup:Configure method...

```
Serilog.ILogger serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents( Configuration.GetValue<string>( "ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey" ) )
            .CreateLogger();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog( serilogLogger );
```

Nothing special. In our controller, we have the following

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create( [FromBody] List<Event> value )
{
   foreach( Event e in value )
   {
      _logger.LogWarning( "***** Event Create {@event}", e );
   }
}
```

What we see in App Insights is the following:

```
{"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"***** Event Create {@event}","DeveloperMode":"true","CategoryName":"Demo.Controllers.EventController","@event":"Demo.Models.Event"}
```

Why is it just giving me the type, and serializing it to Json?
I've tried overloading the ToString method on the Event class and removing the @ from the LogWarning() and we continue to get the type printed out in the logs. In this case it was "string".

Comment: BTW: I set up our code following this demo: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-102-Structured-Logging-with-Application-Insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with help from this page:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data

We added a Destructure.With() call in our Setup, and added a class to handle all destructuring of our data.

```
Serilog.ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
  .WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents(Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"))
  .Destructure.With<DestructureModels>()
  .CreateLogger();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(logger);
```

Our destructuring class looks like this:

```
public class DestructureModels : IDestructuringPolicy
{
    public bool TryDestructure( object value, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory, out LogEventPropertyValue result )
    {
        // to handle custom serialization of objects in the log messages
        //
        if( value.GetType().Namespace.Contains("MyProj.Models"))
        {
            result = new ScalarValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Not prefect, since it only seems to work when set to send to CustomEvents, it won't work with Traces in AppInsights. The destructuring class above will be called, but you won't get the values in AppInsights. Very frustrating the lack of documentation on how/why this stuff works. Also, we need to log explicitly in our code instead of being able to take advantage of AppInsights trace logging.

Comment: You might have a look at [Seq](https://getseq.net/), which works great with Serilog and has a much simpler interface.